# get email from user in nodemailer

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodemailer

I have a contact form using Nodemailer.

This is my code:

```
let mailOptions = {
    from: '<xxx@xxx.com>', // sender address
    to: 'xxx@xxx.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Kontaktanfrage', // Subject line        
    html: output // html body
};
```

In the `from` I have set up my email but I actually want to see email from the user in my inbox.

Can someone help me to do it?

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: What service do you use to send e-mail ? Servers sendmail ? or some other one ?

Comment: I am using Nodejs with Nodemailer @Maielo

Comment: But what are you using as email service. Nodemailer is node.js wrapper for that service it can be sendmail on ur server for example

Comment: You would like to use a package like [**mail-notifier**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-notifier), because nodemailer is not suitable for this kind of stuff, it will not track your inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Node-mailer is used to send the messages you can also check this [reference](https://nodemailer.com/about/)
there are other packages that works for you, you can check these, it might be your workaround

1.[`node-mailin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mailin)
2. [`mailin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailin)